# Подставить следующее число в имя

Tags: windows, bat

Нужно запустить **example.bat** чтобы он выполнял

```
@echo OFF
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO echo exec %%G.txt > %%G.txt
```

Но , текстовик(1.txt) создается с текстом (exec 1.txt) , нужно чтобы скрипт вписывал exec **следующего** .txt файла( т.е в 1.txt -- exec 2.txt и тд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично Я вижу только вариант с добавлением второй переменной и разбиением цикла на несколько строк, для присвоения новой переменной значения на 1 выше значения переменной-счётчика цикла.

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (
set /a j = %%G + 1
echo exec !j!.txt > %%G.txt
)
```

Как-то так.

Такой пример создаст 5 файлов.

В 1.txt будет

```
exec 2.txt
```

Во втором

```
exec 3.txt
```

А в пятом

```
exec 6.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!